# How to connect PostgreSQL in Gradle Project

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, gradle, database-connection, microservices

I am trying to connect PostgreSQL in gradle project. I have a requirement to make CRUD operations.

Comment: The question is too vague. Please do raise the questions after you do your own research and nothing works out.  Also indicate what you have been tried and at which step you failed. We are sure that there are lots of tutorials out there to setup postgres.

Answer (score 9):

Add `PostgreSQL` dependency in `build.gradle`

```
runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
```

then, add the properties in `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=${spring.datasource.url}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

then, Implement `JPA, jdbctemplate,..` in your code.

Comment: Still works great, except now spring.datasurce.platform is deprecated in favor of spring.sql.init.platform.

Comment: The question never asked anything about spring?

Answer (score 0):

In the `build.gradle` file you can copy-paste what is described in the  [MvnRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.6.0) page for pgsql driver inside the Gradle tab.

```
implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:x.y.z'
```

with `x, y, z` representing the version number