# How to use a JDBC driver in a Gradle project?

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle, jdbc

I tried to connect with my PostgreSQL database using the following connection string:

`"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_stock_game"`

I got an error:

> No suitable driver found for "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_stock_game"

I tried both downloading the driver manually (and setting it as a Gradle dependency) and just adding a dependency for Gradle to download.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.stock_game'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    //implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.2'
    implementation files("libs/postgresql-42.5.2")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I tried the two last lines from "dependencies", but got the same error, although I have the driver in Gradle's libs directory (which is in build directory).

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

This is the code I am using to connect to the database, if that is helpful:

```java
private DBConnection() {
    String jdbcConnectionString = "\"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_stock_game\"";
    String user = "postgres";
    String password = "root";
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionString, user, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to establish database connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222401/how-to-connect-postgresql-in-gradle-project  please refer this.

Comment: I added `runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.2'` into my dependencies and i still have the same error. Both with leaving the "implementation" line there or commented out (i don't know much about gradle, so i try different things)

Comment: You have a typo in your connection string, remove the `\"` before and after the actual URL, it should be: `String jdbcConnectionString = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_stock_game";`

Comment: I thought i needed to make a string with quotation marks inside. That's why i escaped these characters.

This connection string worked when i tried to run this not in gradle, so i don't know if that's the issue.

I tried doing what you said and now i get another error, so i will investigate it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I constructed the connection string with quotation marks inside, thinking i needed to include them.

It was like this:
`"\"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_stock_game\""`

Changing it to this:
`"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_stock_game"`
made it work.

Thanks Mark Rotteveel, who spotted that it was an issue.